# How to tell if my process was started from Windows autorun key?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry, windows-explorer

I'm curious if there's a way to know from within my process if it was started from a Windows autorun key?

This one: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

**EDIT:** After posting this question, I discovered that evidently there's a way to find out. [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) knows it somehow:

[image]

Or does it simply scan the registry, looking for a match?

Comment: I don't see any way to distinguish the `HKCU`  autorun programs from any other program launched by Explorer in the user's session. Why do you need to know this?

Comment: @eryksun: If this GUI module was started from autorun it will affect certain UI in it. I tried using command line parameters for that, but it's not very reliable, since anyone can add those too.

Comment: I don't see why it matters that someone can launch the program with the command-line arguments that specify the autorun interface. It's a reliable solution that's simple to implement.

Comment: I don't think microsoft is keeping a history of how the application is launched. Do you just want to keep a single instance of your app? or show it as minimized if it is launched from Windows autorun?

Comment: @Christian-PMP: No, it's not just keeping a single instance. I can do that with a named object. It's more about how that user process behaves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would do this by arranging that the command line for your autorun registry key passed a special argument to indicate that you were starting from autorun. That's your only viable option.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, sadly it seems like the only solution.

Comment: You can kill one of those processes, and start it again. Then kill process explorer and start it again. See what it has to say at that point.

Comment: Oh, I see your point. Yes, that didn't change the autostart column. It must be taking it from the registry by matching process image paths.

Comment: That's the obvious conclusion.